# Trying to translate the last sentence in Thuc. 1.22

Tags: greek, greek-translation

I need to use a Thucydides quote from 'History of the Peloponnesian War', the quote is at the end of [Thuc. 1.22](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Thuc.+1.22&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0105).

> My history is an everlasting possession, not a prize composition which
>   is heard and forgotten.

The English and Spanish translations that I've been reading, while respecting the general meaning of the sentence, vary so wildly, so I tried the lovely method of copying the original:

> κτῆμά τε ἐς αἰεὶ μᾶλλον ἢ ἀγώνισμα ἐς τὸ παραχρῆμα ἀκούειν ξύγκειται.

and, yes!, pasting it into Google Translator.

This is what I got:

> Sooner or later, the sound of the shark is heard.

Yikes! I don't know Greek at all and thus can't show a minimum effort, but I would like an accurate translation of that sentence, hopefully one without sharks.

Comment: Could you edit your question to provide the link to the original, please? So that we could see the whole chapter. And the Spanish translation you mention might also be useful.

Comment: @tum_ The original is already linked but it's a bit hidden. [Same link](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Thuc.+1.22&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0105) and look in the right column for a tab called "Greek (1942)", then click show. It's a nice feature of that site.

Comment: Adding in comments the Spanish translations I've found: "En resumen, mi obra ha sido
compuesta como una adquisición para siempre más que como una pieza de
concurso para escuchar un momento", and "mi obra [...] constituye una conquista para siempre, antes que una obra de concurso para un auditorio circunstancial".

Comment: And [bonus link to the Google Translator result](https://translate.google.es/?hl=en&tab=rT1&authuser=0#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text=%CE%BA%CF%84%E1%BF%86%CE%BC%CE%AC%20%CF%84%CE%B5%20%E1%BC%90%CF%82%20%CE%B1%E1%BC%B0%CE%B5%E1%BD%B6%20%CE%BC%E1%BE%B6%CE%BB%CE%BB%CE%BF%CE%BD%20%E1%BC%A2%20%E1%BC%80%CE%B3%CF%8E%CE%BD%CE%B9%CF%83%CE%BC%CE%B1%20%E1%BC%90%CF%82%20%CF%84%E1%BD%B8%20%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%81%CE%B1%CF%87%CF%81%E1%BF%86%CE%BC%CE%B1%20%E1%BC%80%CE%BA%CE%BF%CF%8D%CE%B5%CE%B9%CE%BD%20%CE%BE%CF%8D%CE%B3%CE%BA%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%84%CE%B1%CE%B9.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- κτῆμα, 'a possession'
- τε, 'and' (postpositive: second word in sentence but translated first)
- ἐς αἰεἰ, 'for always' (prepositional phrase modifying κτῆμα)
- μᾶλλον ἤ, 'rather than'
- ἀγώνισμα, 'a declamation (delivered in a competition)'/'a show-piece'
- ἐς τὸ παραχρῆμα, 'immediately'/'on the spot' (prepositional phrase modifying ἀκούειν)
- ἀκούειν, 'to listen to' (so-called epexegetic infinitive with ἀγώνισμα)
- ξύγκειται, 'it [= Thucydides's history] is being composed' (main verb)

> And it is being composed as a possession for all time rather than as a show-piece to listen to on the spot.

In Google Translate's defense, it seems to be set up to handle modern Greek, not ancient Greek.

Comment: In Latin this could be: "mea vita aeternum donum est, non fabula audiri et deinde ex memoria excidere"?

Comment: Upon reflection, "ex" may be superfluous, as a prefix it is already present in "excidere" providing the "passing out" element. Therefore, returning "memoria" to the nominative: "...deinde memoria excidet".

Comment: The modern Greek mistranslation of Google is stunning indeed; one might think it is a joke of sorts by the programming staff, but it isn't. The program is attempting to morph words into modern Greek words it assumes you misspelled. Chopping up the sentence into shorter phrases gives you even more insights of the fuzzy logic principles of the program.

Comment: @CosmasZachos So, have you managed to figure out where the "shark" comes from?

Comment: @tum. No. It must be some sort of neural network spline program. I *strongly* recommend the following: Start with the full sentence, and stepwise delete words from the beginning, and likewise, from the end. Some "guesses" like land and estate for κτῆμα make sense, but much, including a hiccup in the middle is quite obscure. One is shadow-boxing with fuzzy logic bugs, not dictionaries....

Comment: @CosmasZachos That's exactly what I tried too... but soon just had to give up as it stopped making any sense to me..

Comment: @tum  No, the complete, forward and backward escalation is actually instructive. Deleting the first word (κτῆμα) already eliminates the shark (κῆτος??), but the last few steps are stunning. Their spline finally fit ξύγκειται  to something like  ξύνεται!! I understand Boris Johnson misused this site to fake Ancient Greek translations, oblivious of the off tones the resulting Modern Greek sentence would have had in an ancient Athens spike...

Comment: "spike" as in [workhouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Spike_(essay)).